# Не могу получить html-код страницы

Tags: python, selenium

С помощью библиотеки selenium произвожу вход на страницу, далее перехожу на определенный адрес.
По этому адресу произвожу выбор значения из выпадающего списка:

```
Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "tableTemplate")).select_by_value("2")
```

Далее алгоритм встает на месте. В дальнейшем планируются следующие действия:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Страница грузится бесконечно - свойство сайта.